# javac exception, Java 8

Tags: java

Last week I installed Oracle Java 8 with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Everything seemed to be fine (I continued using my system as normal, can't say exactly what I did over the week). Now, when I execute `java -version` I get

```
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

However, now when I execute `javac -version` I get

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/processing/ProcessingEnvironment
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:54)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

I guess there is some issue with `rt.jar`? What is the best way to proceed here? Should I try uninstalling/reinstalling Java 8? If so, what's the easiest way to do that? Or is there some Java component I'm missing? I want to develop Java programs in Eclipse, and it was my understanding that `oracle-java8-installer` would give me everything I need.

Can someone tell me what is included in "Oracle Java 8"? I know there are lots of Java things I could install, e.g. the JDK, JVM... what are each of these things used for, and am I getting all of the when I install Java 8?

Comment: `rt.jar` is probably corrupt. You can try reinstalling with `sudo rm /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/*.tar.gz; sudo apt-get install --reinstall oracle-java8-installer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rt.jar` is corrupt.

Remove the possibly-corrupt Java installer:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/*.tar.gz
```

Then reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: Any idea how it could have been corrupted?

Comment: Most likely a problem while being downloaded.

Comment: It was working before. The only thing I can think of that might have had an effect is that I installed and removed Eclipse a couple times.

Comment: If it was the one from their website, as recommended (Ubuntu's repo version is quite old), it might. Haven't seen it happen before though.